# How consume Kafka messages from a topic with multiple avro schemas using C# and Confluent.Kafka

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro

I need consume messages from one topic that have multiple avro schemas.

I using a c# lib `Confluent.SchemaRegistry` and `Confluent.Kafka` for make my consumer.

I tried to use a `GenericRecord` Type to deserialize the message without pass the avro schema, but the serialization not working well because return a string with invalid json format.

```
public IConsumer<string, GenericRecord> Consumer =>
    new ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(_consumerConfig)
        .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(
            new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(_schemaRegistryConfig)).AsSyncOverAsync())
        .Build();    

var consumer = _kafkaClienteConsumerFactory.Consumer; 
consumer.Subscribe(_configuration["Kafka:Topic"]);
result = consumer.Consume();
Mensagens.Add(result.Message.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Why does Mensagens need to be a collection of strings? According to what should GenericRecord toString actually return JSON?

Comment: Its return a string, but this topic that I need consume messages have four types (schemas) of messages. I need identify this different schemas and serialize it according the respective type (schema) and convert this messages to json format for next steps of the job.

Comment: Okay, so what is wrong with doing something like `result.Message.Value.Get("Type")`? And writing an if-else against this? In other words, why do you need `ToString` here?

Comment: I don't need use ToString, but I want know how deserialize each message according the respective schema.   How I Map the result on my schema object.

Comment: The `result.Message.Value` is already "deserialized" into `GenericRecord` and you should no longer need any reference to a schema. The type information would be encoded into the Namespace of the Avro object itself (depending on how it was serialized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confluent.Kafka with Confluent.SchemaRegistry doesn't have this feature out of the box.

Some people use double serialization-deserialization approach (Raw record -> Generic Record -> Specific Record) as described [in this article](https://jeremy001181.medium.com/how-to-convert-kafka-message-between-genericrecord-and-specificrecord-f80a4f65c5ee) and [in the conversation of this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1214).

Additionally, you can use my Multi Schema Avro Deserializer [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ycherkes/multi-schema-avro-deserializer), [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YCherkes.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.Avro).
It's mentioned in the [3rd Party Libraries](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/3RD_PARTY.md) of Confluent's .NET Client repository.

Example:

```
IConsumer<string, ISpecificRecord> consumer =
    new ConsumerBuilder<string, ISpecificRecord>(_consumerConfig)
        .SetValueDeserializer(new MultiSchemaAvroDeserializer(
            new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(_schemaRegistryConfig)).AsSyncOverAsync())
        .Build();    

consumer.Subscribe(_configuration["Kafka:Topic"]);
var result = consumer.Consume();
List<ISpecificRecord> Mensagens = new List<ISpecificRecord>();
Mensagens.Add(result.Message.Value);
```

Also, you can look at [kafka-flow](https://github.com/Farfetch/kafka-flow) library. It provides a similar multi-type Avro Serializer-deserializer and dispatcher out of the box.